# Grid stretched upon resizing

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have 3 grids on the same row on a grid. Is there a way to stretch just the middle grid but not the other two upon resizing? All I could do right now is to stretch the last one. 
I have tried to set the middle grid's horizontalAlignment to stretch but then it stretches all the way and even overlapped the last grid without the program running. Still don't quite understand why....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if i understood your layout/plan, but you should be able to do this with the Row/Column in the middle haivng star size.

e.g.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefintions>
        <ColumnDefintion Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefintion Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefintion Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefintions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0">...</Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">...</Grid> <!-- Middle will stretch -->
    <Grid Grid.Column="2">...</Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks. I know I could do that and actually did it in the another row. But an additional grid needs to be added to cover the whole row then split into 3 columns, right? Just wondering if there is another way to do that without adding the grid. But probably the best practice here....

Comment: @NewDTinStackoverlow: Depends, you can often use one Grid and have the controls that should stretch over everything use `Gird.ColumnSpan/RowSpan`. I prefer using many grids though.

Comment: Thanks H.B. It worked perfectly. I actually did similar setups on one of my other rows but all components there stretch the same way. I did not realize that the columndefinition width setup you suggested here is the key to make only one columns stretch but not the others.  Thanks a bundle!